# Using a nuget package produces Core SqlClient Data Provider invalid column error but tests within package are fine

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

[Update: I am able to reproduce in tests by using a dev database - a real SQL db]

I have a project that gets packaged up for use in other projects.  The entities in question are:

```
public class PlatformQuizConfigurationEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class PlatformEnrollmentEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PlatformQuizConfigurationId { get; set; }
    public int? CourseSectionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PlatformQuizConfigurationId")]
    public PlatformQuizConfigurationEntity PlatformQuizConfiguration { get; set; }
    ...

    public int PlatformEnrollmentStatusId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PlatformEnrollmentStatusId")]
    public PlatformEnrollmentStatusEntity PlatformEnrollmentStatus { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public int PlatformEnrollmentDeliveryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PlatformEnrollmentDeliveryId")]
    public PlatformEnrollmentDelivery PlatformEnrollmentDeliveryEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Within the DbContext, I have

```
public virtual DbSet<PlatformEnrollmentEntity> PlatformEnrollments { get; set; }
...
public virtual DbSet<PlatformQuizConfigurationEntity> PlatformQuizConfigurations { get; set; }
...
```

I have test coverage for this which uses in memory sqlite.  I seed PlatformEnrollments with:

```
PlatformQuizConfigurationEntity pqc = _db.PlatformQuizConfigurations
            .SingleOrDefault(s => s.ContinuingEducationData == "dummy-data");
        LtiUserEntity lti = _db.LtiUsers.SingleOrDefault(s => s.PlatformUserId == this.defaultUser.PlatformUserId);

_db.PlatformEnrollments.Add(
            new PlatformEnrollmentEntity
            {
                PlatformQuizConfigurationId = pqc.Id,
                CourseSectionId = 401,
                UserId = lti.Id,
                PlatformEnrollmentStatus = new PlatformEnrollmentStatusEntity
                {
                    IsActive = true,
                    IsActiveUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    IsComplete = false,
                    ReceivedLastChance = false
                },
                PlatformEnrollmentDelivery = new PlatformEnrollmentDeliveryEntity
                {
                    Mode = "email",
                    ModeTarget = "test@example.org",
                    Hour = 15,
                    Minute = 00
                }
            }
        );

_db.SaveChanges();

defaultPlatformEnrollment = _db.PlatformEnrollments.SingleOrDefault(p => p.UserId == lti.Id && p.CourseSectionId == 401);
```

And then a simple test

```
public IPlatformEnrollmentRepository repo = null;
public IPlatformEnrollmentService service = null;

public PlatformEnrollmentsTests()
{
        repo = new PlatformEnrollmentRepository(_db, mapper, loggerFactory);
        service = new PlatformEnrollmentService(repo);
}
...

[Fact]
public async Task PlatformEnrollment_Get()
{
    var existing = await service.GetPlatformEnrollment(defaultPlatformEnrollment.Id);

    Assert.IsType<PlatformEnrollment>(existing);
    Assert.Equal("dummy-data", existing.PlatformQuizConfiguration.ContinuingEducationData);
}
```

The test calls the service

```
public async Task<PlatformEnrollment> GetPlatformEnrollment(int id)
{
    return await _platformRepository.GetPlatformEnrollment(id);
}
```

which calls the repository and returns the Platform enrollment

```
var result = await _db.PlatformEnrollments
                      .AsNoTracking()
                      .Include(p => p.PlatformEnrollmentDelivery)
                      .Include(p => p.PlatformEnrollmentStatus)
                      .Include(p => p.PlatformQuizConfiguration)
                      .Include(p => p.PlatformQuizConfiguration.QuizType)
                      .Include(p => p.PlatformQuizConfiguration.ScheduledQuestions)
                      .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);

return _mapper.Map<PlatformEnrollmentEntity, PlatformEnrollment>(result);
```

The test passes. However, when I package this and install in another project (Azure Functions project, HTTP Trigger), then call it like:

```
var result = await _platformEnrollmentService.GetPlatformEnrollment(id);

if (result == null)
{
    return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);
}

return new OkObjectResult(result);
```

I get a 500 error:

> Executed 'Get_PlatformEnrollment' ()
>
> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Get_PlatformEnrollment. Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Invalid column name 'PlatformQuizConfigurationEntityId'.
>
> Invalid column name 'PlatformQuizConfigurationEntityId'.

No table in the database has a `PlatformQuizConfigurationEntityId` column, only `PlatformQuizConfigurationId` so I'm assuming I just have something in my models/db context misconfigured.

I'm not sure if I need configuration in the project that uses the package, or if I'm missing something in the package.

If I'm missing something in the package, I'm confused why the test is passing.

If I'm missing something in the project that uses the package, that might confuse me even more since the project really doesn't care what the entities look like - it's just passing along relevant status codes and data.

Comment: I would suggest checking your migrations. In your did you build the db from the scratch or used an existing one?

Comment: It is using an existing one, and the migrations exist in another project.  I just tracked down where I made the mistake and will post it

Answer (score 0):

As expected, I messed up a configuration.  In order to reproduce, I updated the test suite to use a real database: our dev instance...

```
var options2 = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<OurDbContext>()
                .UseSqlServer("your database connection string here")
                .Options;
_db = new OurDbContext(options2);
```

Now that I am using this database, I ran the test with a known id:

```
var existing = await service.GetPlatformEnrollment(363);
            Assert.IsType<PlatformEnrollment>(existing);
            Assert.Equal("dummy-data", existing.PlatformQuizConfiguration.ContinuingEducationData);
```

This resulted in the same error I got in testing the project that uses this package.  I commented out all of the includes in the method which resulted in the test not getting the exception.  One by one I added them in until, of course, the last one caused the exception to be thrown.

```
public async Task<PlatformEnrollment> GetPlatformEnrollment(int id)
        {
            var result = await _db.PlatformEnrollments
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(p => p.PlatformEnrollmentDelivery)
                .Include(p => p.PlatformEnrollmentStatus)
                .Include(p => p.PlatformQuizConfiguration)
                .Include(p => p.PlatformQuizConfiguration.QuizType)
                .Include(p => p.PlatformQuizConfiguration.ScheduledQuestions)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
            
            return _mapper.Map<PlatformEnrollmentEntity, PlatformEnrollment>(result);
        }
```

I was missing the Foreign Key Attribute on the property within ScheduledQuestionEntity:

```
[ForeignKey("PlatformQuizConfigurationId")]
        public PlatformQuizConfigurationEntity PlatformQuizConfiguration { get; set; }
```

I have come across some information that leads me to believe foreign keys in sqlite aren't very dependable, which is why the tests were passing in this isolated environment.